# How to get error response with HttpClient and HttpRequestException

Tags: httpwebrequest, httpclient

When I use regular HttpWebRequest in case of server error I'm getting a WebException and can read the response:

```
        if (ex is WebException)
        {
                var wex = (WebException)ex;
                if (wex != null)
                {
                    using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                        errorResponse = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
        }
```

But when I'm using HttpClient it throws HttpRequestException.
How to read the response in this case when error occurs?

Comment: When use HttpClient when HttpWebRequest is working any specific reason?

Comment: I'm using specific features of HttpClient like automatic gzip decompression, etc.. Just wouldn't like to re-develop that code

Comment: Actually i think that is just one line of code:
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

Comment: I have existing code and I want to debug it, I have no option to trace it on http level so that is why I'm trying to read it directly from HttpClient response